# Find points from list that satisfy particular rule AND are within a shape/polygon

Tags: qgis, python, polygon

I have a list of points which I have plotted using rule-based symbology as 4 categories.

I want to produce (and export) a list of the points that satisfy a certain rule (e.g. "pUXO" = 'Y') AND lie inside of my shapefile.

All I can find information about is counting the number of points in a polygon, but I don't want every point, only the ones that satisfy a certain rule.

If there's a way this could be done using the Python console that would be great.

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't aware you can select points within a selection.